# IIS Http Module config file write auto creates .bak file

Tags: config, iis-8

I've got a custom http module in IIS 8 that uses a set of config files to control how it works. These are all named *.config and are mainly in a filesystem folder outside the scope of the site, with one in the bin folder.

In the module I use system.io.file.writealltext to update the files. When I do this, the file I'm writing to is copied to a .bak file before the new file is written to. This only seems to happen when the file extension is .config (I've tested with other extensions and it doesn't happen).

It also doesn't happen everywhere - it happens with all the deployments I have on an Azure Windows Server 2016 VM, but doesn't happen much on other deployments (we have clients with a variety of versions of Win Server & IIS).

I suspect its an IIS setting, to automatically create a .bak when a .config file is changed, but can't find any info on this.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can turn it off?

Comment: IIS don't control httpmodule operation..bak should not be generated by IIS but the code. So please try to set app pool identity to local system and check whether it fix the problem. Besides, microsoft process monitor can monitor file creation. Please check which process and identity created these .bak file.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Thank you for this. It definitely isn't coming from our custom http module, and it only does it on some servers. I've checked several sites today and its stopped doing this now.... I checked the details on some existing .bak sites and it shows the owner as the detail AppPool, even though the site is running under its own AppPool. I'll keep an eye to see when this recurs and then try the Process Monitor as you suggest - thank you.

Comment: App pool execute everything in your application so there's no doubt why the owner is apppool. So monitor when the .bak is created is also important.